# Create host prototype in Zabbix by JSON

Tags: json, zabbix

I created a Template in Zabbix based on JSON using Discovery rule.
While everything is working, items are created if manually create a host and add the created template.
But I would like to create hosts based on data from JSON using Host Prototype.
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOeMl.png**
[image: Host Prototype]
I expect that hosts will be automatically created with items based on Discovery rule.
But I don’t see anything in MONITORING->HOST.
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJnzg.png** 
Zabbix 6.0
[image: monitoring]

Comment: are there errors in the LLD? what are the LLD details?

Comment: I have a master item that receives JSON from a URL (get). Based on this master item, a Discovery rule was created. `{#TVNAME}`= `$.tvName`. Next, using this LLD macro {#IPADDRESS} I try to create HOST PROTOTYPES. If this template is specified for a specific host, then {#TVNAME} is correctly resolved to a value in the LATEST DATA section. There are no errors in LLD.